# Showing that $\sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^\nu}{z + \nu}$ is locally uniformly convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> The series $$\sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^\nu}{z + \nu}$$
>   converges locally uniformly in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$.

Let $z_0 \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$. So since $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$ is open, we can find $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(z_0) \subseteq \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$. Hence we can show that the series converges uniformly in this ball. My idea was to use the Weierstrass criterion, i.e. to find a bound for $$\frac{1}{|z + \nu|} \leq M_\nu$$ for all $z \in B_{\varepsilon}(z_0)$ and $\nu \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum M_\nu < \infty$. I tried to estimate $$\frac{1}{|z + \nu|^2} = \frac{1}{|z|^2 + 2\nu\operatorname{Re}(z) + \nu^2}$$ from above, but somehow I end not up with a nice $M_\nu$. HAs anyone a hint for me? Am I on the right track?

**Edit.** I think it is better to take the neighbourhoods $$B_\varepsilon(0) \cap (\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0})^c$$ where $|z_0| < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s_N(z)$ denote the partial sum of your series. Note that

$$s_{2N+1}(z) = \frac{1}{z(z+1)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(z+2N)(z+2N+1)}$$

while

$$s_{2N}(z) = \frac{1}{z(z+1)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(z+2N-2)(z+2N-1)}-\frac{1}{z+2N}$$

Using this, you can now argue with Weierestrass' idea and use $\sum (z+\nu)^{-2}$ converges.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but I do not quite see yet why this representation of the partial sums is usefull for applying Weierstrass.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Can you under-estimate the norm of $(z+\nu)(z+\nu+1)$? This will bound odd partial sums, and the even partial sums are also uniformly bounded because the norm of $1/|z+2N|$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: I can bound it from below by $||z| - \nu|||z| - (\nu + 1)|$. Also I think that it is better to take neighbourhoods of the form $B_\varepsilon(0) \cap (\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0})^c$. I am sorry that I do not get this proof.