# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z+n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to find the domain of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z+n}$

I recently posted a similar question here: [Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(z^n+\frac{1}{2^nz^n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3751813/736765) where I was able to use Laurent series and find an annulus in which the series does converge.  However, for this problem, I am not sure if I can do that.  The ratio and root test don't help too much either.  So, I was wondering if there is a way to apply, maybe, Leibniz's criterion to a series of a complex variable?  What would something like that look like?  Maybe there is something else that would work?  Any ideas, hints, etc. are (as always) greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2182485

Comment: Both duplicates found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5En%7D%7Bz%2Bn%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series is not defined when $z \in \{0,-1,-2,...\}$. Assume that $z \notin \{0,-1,-2,...\}$ and consider $\sum (-1)^{n} [\frac  1  {z+n} -\frac  1 n] =\sum (-1)^{n} z\frac  1  {n(z+n)}$. Check that this series is absolutely convergent. Since $\sum  (-1)^{n} /n$ is convergent it follows that the given series converges whenever $z \notin \{0,-1,-2,...\}$.

Comment: I found two answers in less than a minute (the first one identical to yours). Once again I wonder if you ever check for duplicates.

Comment: I'm sorry about this - I should have done a better job of checking before I posted.  Thank you, Martin, for always helping, and thank you, Kavi, for answering so quickly.  It is all very much appreciated :)